# FabricJS - Custom type not renders on LoadFromJSON

Tags: fabricjs

After loading canvas data from JSON, an element with the custom type attribute isn't renders.

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/redlive/pnkfsvdk/).

Steps to reproduce are:

1) Click on SAVE button

2) Mover RED element somewhere

3) Click on RESTORE button

Nothing happens, but if the type attribute is commented out, then everything works just perfect.

Not sure if it's a bug or I forgot to add something...
Tnx

```js
fabric.ContainerRect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
  type: 'container-rect',
  initialize: function(options) {

    this.callSuper('initialize', options);

    this.on('moving', function() {
      // console.log('Red is moving...');
    });
  },
  _render: function(ctx) {
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
  }
});

fabric.ContainerRect.fromObject = function(options) {
  return new fabric.ContainerRect(options);
}

//==========================================================================================
let store;
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');
const canvasOriginalSize = {
  width: 600,
  height: 600
};

const redBox = new fabric.ContainerRect({
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: 'red'
});

canvas.add(redBox);
canvas.renderAll();


$("#save").on('click', function() {
  store = canvas.toJSON();
  console.log(store);
});

$("#restore").on('click', function() {
  canvas.loadFromJSON(store, function() {
    //console.log('restored:', canvas.getObjects());
    //canvas.renderAll();
  });
});
```

```css
#paper {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.3/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
<button id="save">Save to JSON</button>
<button id="restore">Restore form JSON</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fabric.ContainerRect.fromObject = function(object, callback) {
  return fabric.Object._fromObject('ContainerRect', object, callback);
};
```

You need to use callback in `fromObject`.

If you remove type then it takes `rect` type for its object and while loadingfrom json it takes `fabric.Rect.fromObject` method not your `fabric.ContainerRect.fromObject`, thats why working.

***DEMO***

```js
fabric.ContainerRect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
  type: 'container-rect',
  initialize: function(options) {

    this.callSuper('initialize', options);

    this.on('moving', function() {
      // console.log('Red is moving...');
    });
  },
  _render: function(ctx) {
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
  }
});

fabric.ContainerRect.fromObject = function(object, callback) {
  return fabric.Object._fromObject('ContainerRect', object, callback);
};

//==========================================================================================
let store;
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');
const canvasOriginalSize = {
  width: 600,
  height: 600
};

const redBox = new fabric.ContainerRect({
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: 'red'
});

canvas.add(redBox);
canvas.renderAll();


$("#save").on('click', function() {
  store = canvas.toJSON();
  console.log(store);
});

$("#restore").on('click', function() {
  canvas.loadFromJSON(store, function() {
    console.log('restored:');
  });
});
```

```css
#paper {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.3/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
<button id="save">Save to JSON</button>
<button id="restore">Restore form JSON</button>
```